# How can I use opencv python cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT as imput for cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.1

I made a stabilizer for videos and now I'm trying to compare my algorithm with others, so I wanted to implement the sift and pass the keypoints to the optical flow algorithm.

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

then

```
frame.features = sift.detect(frame_img_gray,None)
new_features, _, _ = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_frame_img, frame_img, prev_frame.features, None, **lk_params)
        new_features_for_validation, _, _ = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame_img, prev_frame_img, new_features, None,**lk_params)
```

So I get this message from the compiler:

```
 new_features, _, _ = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_frame_img, frame_img, prev_frame.features, None, **lk_params)
TypeError: prevPts is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually reshape SIFT output to be suitable for cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK:

```
LK_pts=np.empty((0,1,2), np.float32)
for pts  in prev_frame.features:
    x, y = pts.pt
    LK_pts=np.append(LK_pts,np.array([[[x,y]]],dtype=np.float32),axis=0)
```

Comment: @SamuelMarcosSherman appending in numpy is extremely slow. Instead `np.array([[[f.pt[0], f.pt[1]]] for f in frame.features])` would be faster. You're still iterating through all the features but not appending.

Comment: Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in cv::`anonymous-namespace'::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlowImpl::calc, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\video\src\lkpyramid.cpp, line 1244

Comment: LK_pts = np.array([[[f.pt[0], f.pt[1]]] for f in frame.features], np.float32)